# In matlab function interp1- does the order of the new positions, for which the function values are interpolated, matter?

Tags: matlab

Regarding matalb function yi=interp1(x,Y,xi,method) where x are the positions of the known values of Y, and xi are the new positions, whose Y values need to be interpolated - does the xi values need to be ordered for the function interp1 to work properly?

Comment: As m.s. noted, the answer is no.  However, sorting some vectors can speed up the computation.  For example, if `x` is sorted, you can use the quicker function `interp1q` instead.  If both `x` and `xi` are sorted, you could theoretically use a function even faster than `interp1q` which would step through both vectors simultaneously.  However, I don't think such a built-in MATLAB function exists.

Answer (score 1):

No, the query points `xq` do not have to be sorted.

Consider the following example:

```
x = 0:pi/4:2*pi;
v = sin(x);

xq_sorted = 0:pi/16:2*pi;

% shuffle the query points randomly
shuffle = randperm(length(xq_sorted));
xq_shuffled=xq_sorted(shuffle);

% interpolate both the sorted and the shuffled query points
vq_sorted = interp1(x,v,xq_sorted);
vq_shuffled = interp1(x,v,xq_shuffled);

% compare results
if any(vq_sorted(shuffle)~=vq_shuffled)
    disp('interpolation results do not match');
else
    disp('interpolation results match');
end
```

**output**

```
interpolation results match
```